Shipping address issue in store pickup
I've enabled in-store pickup as delivery method in my store but I'm facing an issue.
When I try to place an order using in-store pickup method, the following error message appear :
Please check the shipping address information. "regionId" is required. enter and try again.

While if other delivery method selected, the order placed successfully!
Could you please help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Just shooting in the dark here, but maybe the store you are trying to use a pickup does not have a proper region set.

Hi @Marius thank you.. it's solved.. but other error appear ( qoute does not have pickup location assigned ).
